# How to make it cleanly from for to Stream (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

```
fun render(params: Map<String, String>): String {
    var acc:String = template
    for (entry in params.entries){
        acc = acc.replace("@${entry.key}", entry.value)
    }
    return acc
}
```

Hello, I would like to make it cleanly using stream or something like that.

Could you help me?

Comment: just use `map` instead of this function you made, it will be more clear.

Comment: @Daniel this is not a use case for `map`, it doesn't return a collection

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in a functional way would be to use `fold`:

```
fun render(params: Map<String, String>): String =
    params.entries.fold(template) { acc, entry -> 
        acc.replace("@${entry.key}", entry.value)
    }
```

Comment: Thx :) It's the answer i wanted!